# Where do two objects meet if one is dropped and the other is thrown upwards after two seconds?

Tags: derivatives, classical-mechanics

A body is dropped from a height of 100 yards. After falling for 2 seconds a second body is projected vertically upward from a point on the earth directly below and with a velocity of 40 yd/sec (yards per second). Find the time and height at which the two bodies meet.

My logic is as follows:

$s_1=-16t^2+100$ for the object being dropped.

The next step I think is more complicated, I assume that:

when $t=2, v_2=-32t+c, 40=-64+c, c=104$

Therefore, $s_2=-16t^2+104t$

When $s_1=s_2$,

$-16t^2+100=-16t^2+104t, t=\frac{100}{104}$

This is the wrong answer however, could somebody please explain how to do this correctly?

Comment: Where does the $-16$ come from?

Comment: Isn't the acceleration of gravity approximately $10.72$ yards per second? (I feel super awkward writing with those units, but what can you do ...)

Comment: Ah, I see, yes I used -16 to imply negative acceleration due to gravity but perhaps I need to convert this number from feet to yards.

Comment: Does that sove your problem?

Comment: No, I am still getting the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You project the object after $2$ seconds so it travels for $t-2$ seconds.

So the distance traveled by object projected = $40(t-2) - \frac{g}{2}(t-2)^2$

Distance traveled by dropped object $= \frac{g}{2}t^2$ where $g$ is the gravity.

So total distance $100 = \frac{g}{2}t^2 + 40t - 80 - \frac{g}{2}t^2+2gt-2g$

$(2g+40)t = 180+2g \implies t = \frac{90+g}{20+g}$.

Comment: Hi, thank you, this seems to be very clear but the answer given is 3.3 seconds after the first ball is dropped. Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: @OpenSauce If I substitute $g = 10.72$ yards / $s^2$, that is what I get for $t$.

Comment: and I get height from the ground as $\approx 41.6$ yards.

Comment: Thank you! I had the wrong conversion using an online tool, but this works out correctly.